# How to write SQL query for aggregate total value for a particular condition

Tags: sql

vote table

```
PK_ID  ob_type  ob_id  VOTE   user_id  VOTED_ON
    1      100      1     1   NISHANT  02/08/10
    2      100      1     1      DEVI  02/08/10
    3      100      1     1  VIRENDRA  02/08/10
    4      100      1     0       XYZ  02/08/10
    5      200      1     1     XCXCX  02/08/10
    6      200      1     1       CXC  03/02/11
    7      200      1     0      XCCX  03/02/11
    8      200      1     0      XCCX  03/02/11
    9      300      1     1    XCCXXC  03/02/11
   10      300      1     1      XCCX  03/02/11
   11      300      1     1        SD  02/08/10
   12      300      1     0   XCCXXCC  02/08/10
   13      400      4     0    CXXCXC  02/08/10
   14      400      4     0      XCCX  03/02/11
   15      400      4     0       CXC  03/02/11
   16      400      1     1       CXC  03/02/11
```

here I want to calculate total no of vote on a particular object type and id.

```
  SELECT 
     COUNT (ALL  [PK_ID]) AS [TOTAL_VOTE],
     COALESCE (
         ( SELECT 
               [IS_THUMBS_UP]
           FROM
               [votetable]
           WHERE
               [ob_type] = 400 AND
               [ob_id] = 4 AND
               [FK_VOTED_BY] = Nishant ),-1) AS [MY_VOTING]  
  FROM  
     [votetable]
  WHERE
     [ob_type] = 400 AND
     [ob_id]  = 4
```

Here it give result

total vote = 4
and my vote = 0

but here total voting is -2 (bcz 3 false(0) and 1 true)

So how do I get the correct value.

Comment: There are no rows in the data shown with an ob_id of 4.  Which is wrong - the data or the expected result?

Comment: I don't really see how you get any results, if you're restricting to just those with `ob_type = 100 and ob_id = 4`

Comment: sir now i have edited u can see..

Comment: even from the edited data, there are no rows where both ob_id = 4 **and** ob_type = 100 - your results would therefore still be 0 and -1 (the latter result from the coalesce). You have also forgotten to include quotation marks around the user's name.

Comment: ...and from the latest version, it should return 3 and -1 - there are three rows where both ob_type = 400 and ob_id = 4, but none where ob_type = 400, ob_id = 4 and user_id is NISHANT. You still haven't included quotation marks around the user's name, and some of the columns have different names in the query to those in the supplied data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest (SQLServer syntax) :

```
select sum(case [VOTE] when 1 then 1 else -1 end) as total_votes,
       sum((case [VOTE] when 1 then 1 else -1 end) *  
           (case when [user_id] = @username then 1 else 0) as user_votes
from [votetable]
where [ob_type] = @obtype and [ob_id] = @obid
```

@username, @obtype and @obid are variables with the desired user's name, object type and object ID.